# how do i create a new DIV each time a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to create a DIV with 100x100 px and it shold be red, every time a button is clicked, i  did this code but its not working:

```
    <html>
<title>
    create new div
</title>

<body>
<button id="createsquare">
Cria QUADRADO
</button>

<script>
function fcreatesquare()
{
var crsq = document.createElement('div', 'id=created', 'widght=100px', 'wheidght=100px','color=black');
return crsq;
}

    var createsquare = document.getElementById('createsquare');
    createsquare.onclick(fcreatesquare);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically create a div with dynamic onclick function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54852994/dynamically-create-a-div-with-dynamic-onclick-function)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `appendChild` function: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

```
function fcreatesquare() {
var crsq = document.createElement('div', 'id=created', 'widght=100px', 'wheidght=100px','color=black');
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(crsq);
}
```